# Qliksense Extension - Select Values

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I need to pass the value 'A' to be selected into a Qliksense extension. This extension contains 1 dimension and 1 measure. I would like 'A' to be selected in the 1 dimension.

It seems that `self.selectValues(0, 'A', false);` is the call for this. I can't get this to work at all.

How do I select 'A' in this extension or the underlying table?

Details:

I have the following code inside the paint function that renders the data (this part works):

```
                    // iterate over all rows
                    var hc = layout.qHyperCube;
                    for (var r = 0; r < hc.qDataPages[0].qMatrix.length; r++) {
                        table += '<tr>';

                        // iterate over all cells within a row
                        for (var c = 0; c < hc.qDataPages[0].qMatrix[r].length; c++) {
                            table += '<td>';
                                table += hc.qDataPages[0].qMatrix[r][c].qText;
                            table += '</td>';
                        }
                        table += '</tr>';
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method expects an array and the element number of the dimension value, so this should work:

```
self.selectValues(0, [qElemNumber], false);
```

Comment: So, this is the elemNumber, how would I pass a value of my choice in? Such as passing a business unite 'HR' in there?

Comment: If 'HR' is element of dimension values (in qText) you will need to get qElemNumber of 'HR' out of qMatrix.

Comment: Just had a chance to try this way of doing it. It works.